Domestic Air Travel within the US with Limited Term Driver's License and no passport, for non-resident aliens?
I am a non-resident alien in the US. Can I fly domestically without my passport, clearing  TSA checks with my Driving License?
My driving license is real-id compliant, and is current (not expired). However, it does have a label on it saying, "limited term", like this:

From the TSA website:

A temporary driver's license is not an acceptable form of identification.

Does this disqualify my license?
The reason I do not want to carry my passport is because of safety. It seems better to leave it at home, rather than carry it with me when I am out and about.

Edit: My travel was successful and I used just my license

@NateEldredge The Texas information is here

Of course, all drivers licenses are "limited term" - they have an expiration date.

@JonCuster As the link above your comment explains, "limited term" means the license expires when the holder's period of lawful presence expires. Because this changes, e.g. they leave school or they get fired from their H-2B job, the period of validity may be shorter than that printed on the card.

@user71659 - and if the license is scanned by TSA they will be alerted to that fact. The gold star in the upper right (nicely worked in to be the Texas star) indicates that the license complies with RealID.

A temporary license refers to the paper printout given to you while waiting for the real card to arrive by mail.
A limited term card is perfectly fine for identification, I've gotten past TSA without any issues all the time.

Thanks. I got past TSA with my license
